# Send GET and POST requests via one Ajax function and FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've written a function which handles all `form` submits.
The result is always html, which I insert into my `content`-div. That's why I prevent the default event.

The function should handle post requests (including files) and get requests.

I'm using `FormData`. To handle the requests I set following configuration:

- post

  - `processData` = `false`
  - `contentType` = `false`
- get

  - `processData` = `true` (default)
  - `contentType` = `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` (default)

But when I fire get requests, I get:

> TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface FormData.

I could fix this error when setting both settings to `false`, but then no data is submitted.

```
$('#content').on('submit', 'form', function(event) { // apply to all form-elements in the content-div
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: formData,
        processData: ($form.attr('method') === 'GET'),
        contentType: ($form.attr('method') === 'GET') ? 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' : false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $('#content').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          //
        }
    })
});
```

This would work:

```
data: ($form.attr('method') === 'GET') ? $form.serialize() : new FormData(this),
```

Does this mean I can't use `FormData` for get requests? Or how can I modify my snippet to handle both request types successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a config object for this situation.

```
var ajaxConfig = { 
   url: $form.attr('action'),
   type: $form.attr('method'),
   processData: ($form.attr('method') === 'GET'),
   contentType: ($form.attr('method') === 'GET') ?
       'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' : false
};

if($form.attr('method') === 'POST') {
    ajaxConfig.data = formData;
}

$.ajax(ajaxConfig);
```

Comment: So you're sending no data if it's a GET-request!?

Comment: just a sample for it for get request u can set data to  $form.serialize()

Comment: So it's not possible to get the data with `FormData` in a get request?

Comment: you are not passing content-type, that's why it's expecting the data to be a text but i guess you are trying to pass a json object.

Either change the content type or serialize the data :)